# How do I make a URL for Jsoup to parse?

Tags: java, url, jsoup

So I'm making a program that extracts the lyrics from a user given song off of AZ Lyrics.
The problem I'm having is that after converting the string to a URL, it says Jsoup is not able to parse it because it doesn't accept strings despite the variable being a URL that we are passing in.

```
String strURL = "http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/" + artist + "/" + song + ".html"; 

URL url = new URL(strURL);

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url);
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is the value for artist and song variables?

Comment: @SyamS They are strings entered by the user using a textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know which version of [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/) your are using, but as per latest version the parse method with url alone is not available. You need to pass a timeOut. So try

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 30000);
```

There is a connect method which would be the best option (IMO). You could pass the stringURL variable directly. Try

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(strURL).get();
```

If these didn't help check the value of artist and song variables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the string `strURL` to `URL`, this should work:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/" + artist + "/" + song + ".html").timeout(10000).get();
String html = doc.text();
```

I've set a timeout of 10 seconds, adjust to fit your needs.

---

You can take a look at the available methods [here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html)